# How does energy recovery recuperator work

Tags: heat-exchanger

In a recuperator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recuperator, sensible heat can be transfered by thermal conduction through the plates, and latent heat can also be transfered when the high temperature side has some condensation.

There seems to be recuperator products in which water molecule can go through the plate from one side to another. For example in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_recovery_ventilation:

> Enthalpy plates were introduced 2006 by Paul, a special company for
>   ventilation systems for passive houses. A crosscurrent countercurrent
>   air-to-air heat exchanger built **with a humidity permeable material**.
>   Polymer fixed-plate countercurrent energy recovery ventilators were
>   introduced in 1998 by Building Performance Equipment (BPE), a
>   residential, commercial, and industrial air-to-air energy recovery
>   manufacturer.

How does such "humidity permeable material" work?

If what is transfered is liquid water after condensation, then draining away the condensed water on one side and supply (from water supply) some fresh water into the pipe on another side will have the same effect (if there is any effect), there is no need for the plate to be water permeable at all which will reduce the isolation.

If what is transfered is steam, then how can a material permeable to steam but not permeable to other gas like CO2?